# Detecting MS Edge with hisorange/browser-detect in PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5, microsoft-edge

I am trying to detect Microsoft Edge using hisorange/browser-detect package in my Laravel 5.2 project.

As I understand, I should merely write Browser::isIE() to detect Internet Explorer and Edge, but unfortunately it shows only Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the developers you have to check for Microsoft Edge like this:

```
Browser::isIE(true);
```

This will include the Trident into the matching.

It was not added originally because the Trident is not a traditional IE update.

In order to detect Microsoft edge yourself just do:

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
preg_match('/Edge/i', $user_agent)
```